# Use ruby gem from git repo via Bundler

Tags: ruby, git, rubygems, bundler

I have created a custom gem using bundler and checked it in a git repo.

custom_gem.rb

```
require "custom_gem/version"
require "custom_gem/custom_class"

module CustomGem
  # Your code goes here...
end
```

custom_class.rb

```
require 'typhoeus'

module CustomGem

  class CustomClass

    def self.custom_method
       #do stuff with typhoeus
    end

  end

end
```

Added it as a dependency to another project and installed it via bundler.

```
gem 'custom_gem', :git => 'git@bitbucket.org:dir/repo.git'
```

After that I try to use it by calling

```
CustomGem::CustomClass.custom_method
```

and I get the following error:

***uninitialized constant CustomGem::CustomClass***

Any suggestions?

Might be a small thing but just starting out with ruby so any advice would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things to check :

1. What happens when you run Bundle install (is the gem listed as installed ?)
2. Did you require the gem properly (require 'custom_gem') ? Rails does a little magic there, but I'm not sure if you are in a rails application.

Comment: bundle install lists the gem. I'm not using rails but I have included the require statement

Comment: Can you try a simple defined?(CustomGem) in the app using it (it would allow to know if it is the whole module that is not known, or only the class inside).

Comment: puts defined? CustomGem  outputs Constant

Comment: Getting there, so your gem is installed, your module (CustomGem) is known from your application (as per the defined? output), so it looks the problem is with the class. Double check the name (typo's do happen) and as per Joshua's answer the paths. Post them if everything looks ok to you (gem file structure essentially).

Answer (score 1):

The file custom_gem.rb should be in **lib/custom_gem.rb**, and the file custom_class.rb should be in **lib/custom_gem/custom_class.rb**

```
lib/custom_gem/custom_class.rb
\_/ \________________________/
 |             |
 |              \_ comes from your code: `require "custom_gem/custom_class"`
 |
 |
  \_ comes from custom_gem.gempsec (the line `s.require_paths = ["lib"]`)
```

For more about the load path, file hierarchy and naming, check out this [gem guide](http://guides.rubygems.org/patterns/).

Comment: these are the paths that I am currently using so theoretically it should be ok

Comment: Okay, a big list then: Did you run the code with `bundle exec`? What does the require statement return? What does `$ bundle exec gem which custom_gem` return? What happens if you directly require that file using `require "custom_gem/custom_class"`? Is there possibly another file with the same name as custom_gem that is getting required instead?

Comment: I ran bundle exec gem which and got the path where the gem is stored. Looks like it is not getting my latest files from the git repo because the Module is not specified in my custom_class.rb file

Comment: I think that I need to reinstall the gem each time a make a change in the repo, not sure about this

Comment: If you are developing on both the gem and the app, the simplest way is to use the path option : http://gembundler.com/v1.3/gemfile.html, so you do not need to reinstall each time.

Comment: Thanks Martin, that seems to solve my problem. I will keep using path while in development and when finished I will switch back to git.